# maintaining consistent matplotlib axes limits

Tags: python, matplotlib, equals

I'm trying to produce a series of figures showing geometric shapes of different sizes (one shape in each figure) but consistent, equal-spacing axes across each figure. I can't seem to get `axis('equal')` to play nice with `set_xlim` in matplotlib.

Here's the closest I've come so far:

```
pts0 = np.array([[13,34], [5,1], [ 0,0], [7,36], [13,34]], dtype=np.uint8)
pts1 = np.array([[10,82], [119,64], [149,63], [136,0], [82,14], [81,18], 
[26,34], [3,29], [0,34], [10,82]], dtype=np.uint8)

shapes = [pts0,pts1]
for i in range(2):
    pts = shapes[i]   
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    plotShape = patches.Polygon(pts, True, fill=True)
    p = PatchCollection([plotShape], cmap=cm.Greens)
    color = [99]
    p.set_clim([0, 100])
    p.set_array(np.array(color))
    ax1.add_collection(p)
    ax1.axis('equal')
    ax1.set_xlim(-5,200)
    ax1.set_ylim(-5,200)
    ax1.set_title('pts'+str(i))
    plt.show()
```

In my system, this results in two figures with the same axes, but neither one of them shows y=0 or the lower portion of the shape. If I remove the line `ax1.set_ylim(-5,200)`, then figure "pts1" looks correct, but the limits of figure "pts0" are such that the shape doesn't show up at all.

My ideal situation is to "anchor" the lower-left corner of the figures at (-5,-5), define xlim as 200, and allow the scaling of the x axis and the value of ymax to "float" as the figure windows are resized, but right now I'd be happy just to consistently get the shapes inside the figures.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can define one of your axes independently first and then when you define the second axis use the **sharex** or **sharey** arguments

```
new_ax = fig.add_axes([<bounds>], sharex=old_ax)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That helps me place the axes more precisely on the canvas, but I get the same behavior with the limits and scale... the polygon is cut off or out-of-pane entirely.